# Showing a custom popup window from a Catch statement inside a Task

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a WPF window that I want to use instead of the regular Windows.MessageBox mostly because I want it to have a "Details" box to show the guts of the error.  This works fine until I start getting into threading.

I want to run a Task that will get a list of, for example, Tables in a SQL Server database which might take a little while.  If there is an error - say a timeout when attempting to connect - I want to show the custom popup with the exception details.

At fist it keep crashing.  After some reading (that to you guys here on SO), it dawned on me that the Task was not in the UI thread and cannot show a window (the native MessageBox does still work it seems).  So, I came up with the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());
    }

    void DoWork()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Window1 popup = new Window1();
            popup.Show();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

This is a temp app I made so I could demonstrate the basics of what I am doing.  In the main app I am sending the exception as an argument to the popup window.

My question is this:  Is this the best way to do this?  It seems to work fine but wasnt 100% sure that it was the best practice to mix threads like this and thought I would put it out there.

If it is good solution, my next question would be how do I tie back the popup with the parent window so the user is prevented from closing the parent while the popup is open or the popup closes automatically when the parent closes?  The Parent itself will not be the main application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to show the window on the main UI thread of your application.

You could do that by passing a `Dispatcher` to `DoWork()`. But it also make sense to separate the concerns of performing the calculation and showing the error. So, what you can do instead is to let `DoWork()` throw and handle the exception in a continuation of the `Task`. The continuation will run only when an error occurs and will run in the context of the main UI thread:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork)
        .ContinueWith(
            task => ErrorBox.Show(task.Exception),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void DoWork()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

(Assuming `ErrorBox.Show()` creates and shows the window.)

Comment: Beautiful!  That worked perfectly.  The key was setting the TaskScheduler.  Thanks for the help!!  Only weird thing i have now is that if I put a breakpoint right before the .Show() of the popup and then hit next it locks up the program but with no break point it works fine.  Seems to be a problem with my popup so I have to look into it.